# Uncaught TypeError even if typeof is used in if clause

Tags: javascript

```
$.each(res.data,function(idx,val){
if (typeof val.location.longitude != 'undefined') {
 console.log(val.name + ':' + val.location.latitude + ', ' + val.location.longitude);
}
```

why is this still true and returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'longitude' of undefined
```

even if longitude is not defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking the wrong thing:

```
if (typeof val.location != 'undefined')
  // ...
```

The error message is telling you that `val.location` is `undefined`, not that the "longitude" property is `undefined`. It's, "Hello I cannot read the value of a property called 'longitude' from something whose value is `undefined`", in other words.